# PhpStorm not receiving Xdebug from Vagrant machine

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, development-environment

I've a Vagrant VM for dev with xdebug installed and I want to connect it to PhpStorm.

In my `xdebug.ini` I have this:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.56.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

But it doesn't work. I did some debug and I check that in my host machine the 9001 port was open, and it is:

```
phpstorm  311 jose   41u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b107d1be65      0t0  TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
phpstorm  311 jose   42u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b1056e5245      0t0  TCP *:10137 (LISTEN)
phpstorm  311 jose  143u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b10ae27e65      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6942 (LISTEN)
phpstorm  311 jose  168u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b107cd875d      0t0  TCP *:20080 (LISTEN)
phpstorm  311 jose  342u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b110c70245      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:63342 (LISTEN)
JuniperSe 497 jose   10u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b10696675d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3333 (LISTEN)
VBoxHeadl 726 jose   24u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b1086e6b3d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:2222 (LISTEN)
VBoxHeadl 726 jose   25u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b10fe1d435      0t0  TCP *:33060 (LISTEN)
VBoxHeadl 726 jose   26u  IPv4 0x2b62c0b108709435      0t0  TCP *:8088 (LISTEN)
```

But from Vagrant the 9001 port is not accessible:

```
nc -z -v -w5 192.168.56.1 9001
nc: connect to 192.168.56.1 port 9001 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

And that's the same for all PhpStorm ports. But I can access 8088 or 33060

```
nc -z -v -w5 192.168.56.1 8088
Connection to 192.168.56.1 8088 port [tcp/omniorb] succeeded!
```

I've checked the option to accept external connections in PhpStorm for xdebug. I'm using Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, very silly problem. I had the external connections blocked for phpstorm, I changed that in `System Preferences > Security > Firewall`, on the list of apps I searched phpstorm and allow external connections

Comment: You have solved it -- great. But here are my comments anyway: 1) you have `xdebug.remote_connect_back = on` -- with this option ON the value of `xdebug.remote_host` is ignored ... so no reason specifying them both. 2) *"But I can access 8088 or 33060"* So .. you are connecting from Vagrant machine to your Host .. which then redirects you back to Vagrant machine (as those ports are served by VM/Guest OS)...

Comment: @LazyOne actually I still have problems, I'm trying to debug php client debug, and it doesn't seems to be working at all, I run php files and I don't receive anything on PhpStorm

Comment: Disable `xdebug.remote_connect_back` option then and let it connect to predefined IP (maybe xdebug detects wrong IP). If still the same -- collect xdebug log -- it should tell exactly where it tries to connect and what happens there (at least you will see if connection is successful or not) .. which will give further hints.

Comment: updated the xdebug config, added the log but the file it doesnt get created. I guess everytime a php file is run from the command line this should be logging something on it, don't it?

Comment: Not every time -- only when it sees debug request (xdebug cookie etc). But you can set `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` and xdebug will attempt to debug every single script. Please also note that you **may** have different php.ini files for your PHP that runs in CLI mode and run by Apache (if that's what you use as web server). If you trying to debug a web page via browser -- see xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser (to confirm current settings).